# Can I replace moldy insulation in an air handler?

Tags: hvac, insulation

I found a little mold on the foil covering the insulation in my TWE030C140B0 air handler/ AC/Heater.  I am 95% sure I have the moisture problem resolved and now I need to replace the insulation.

Does anyone have any advice for this?  It looks like the whole thing, blower and coils and all, has to come out to get to some of it.

I'm in a bit of a financial pickle, and if this can be DIY'd at all, it'd really save my bacon.

Answer (score 1):

If the evaporator has to come out, you'll likely have to recover the refrigerant first.  Unless you have the proper equipment, you're not going to be able to do it yourself.  Even if you have the equipment, you may also need to be certified to complete the work.

If you can replace the insulation without removing/damaging the refrigerant lines, then you might be able to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just spray the affected insulation with a 3% hydrogen peroxide and water solution. The peroxide will kill the mold. Most of the units I have installed have the insulation on the outside of the air handler but some are inside, the line set has some flex to it but the connecting duct work would make it difficult to remove the sheet metal, in most cases the evaporator is just sitting on top of an up flow furnace with just a couple of screws holding it in position. I have had to pull evaporators in the past and disassembling the duct work is the toughest part. If the sheet metal needs to be removed and the line set is not locked in the sheet metal can be removed from the evaporator coils, this would also be a good time to get a non acid coil cleaner and clean the evaporator coil/ fins you may say they look clean but it is amazing how much dust is hiding in those fins.